# Does Wat Tambor actually die?

Tags: star-wars

After watching the scene where the CIS leaders are slaughtered by Darth Vader, I noticed something. We never actually see Wat Tambor die. The last we see of him is when he cowers behind a table in a conference room. Then it looks like Vader turns away from him, and then deactivates his light saber. According to the Wookieepedia he is killed by Vader, but we never see him die. I read that he dies in a deleted scene, but is this canon, Shaak Ti dies on the Invisible Hand, but I don't think that's canon. So is his death canon?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wat's death is canonically confirmed on the [Star Wars Databank](https://www.starwars.com/emir-wat-tambor-biography-gallery) website.

[image]
<sub><sup>"Tambor was on Mustafar when Darth Vader arrived with orders to eliminate the Separatist leadership. He impaled the Techno Union leader with his lightsaber, killing him"</sup></sub>

and in the [Ultimate Star Wars](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars) factbook.

> *He [Wat] later perishes on Mustafar*

---

As to the *specifics* of his death, that's described in the film's [official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel));

> The head of the Techno Union turned at his approach, cringing, arms
>   lifted to shield his faceplate from the flames in the dragon’s eyes.
>   “Please, I’ll give you anything. Anything you want!”
>
> The blade flashed twice; Tambor’s arms fell to the floor, followed by
>   his head. “Thank you.”

In the [Illustrated Screenplay](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith:_Illustrated_Screenplay)

> RUNE is cut down. NUTE GUNRAY crawls out from under the table and
>   opens the Main Door, allowing DESTROYER DROIDS to enter. **WAT TAMBOR is
>   cut down**, along with SHU MAI. DESTROYER DROIDS appear in the doorway
>   and blast away, causing total destruction. When the firing is over,
>   ANAKIN is gone. Blown away? No. ANAKIN drops from the ceiling behind
>   the TWO DROIDS and cuts them to pieces before they know what hit them.

and in the [Dark Horse Comics graphic novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(comics))

[image]

and this still image of the (deleted) scene in which he dies.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

We see Wat Tambor's corpse at about 1:36:43 in *Revenge of the Sith.*

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot that proves this?